# number ticker with infinite loop until stop button is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops, onclick

Have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vuofxovb/1/

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900);
 .square {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
  margin: 1.66%;
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
  /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
  width: 90%;
  /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
  padding: 5%;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/*  For list */

ul {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 5% 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
li {
  margin: 0 0 0 5%;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ECECEC;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
.numbers {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 75px;
}
.text {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell text">
        START
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell text">
        STOP
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        6
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        7
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        8
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        9
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have 9 numbers in a 3 x 3 grid. The top line has Start button on the left, Stop button at the right and a blank square in the middle. I wish to have a counter at the middle square running in an infinite loop when START is clicked. This middle square will have numbers placed in the 3 x 3 grid (on a random sort - not a proper ascending or descending). The loop will stop by clicking the Stop button. I tried finding a solution in few javascripts and php forums but unable to find something that will increment numbers within the same DIV

Comment: Post code here instead of referring to off-site resources. You should also check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setInterval` which calls a function every x miliseconds.

Use an array (1 to 9) to shuffle, so you randomise the numbers without duplicates. I used the external library underscore.js but there are loads of other methods to do this.

Then use `clearInterval` to stop:-

your working code:-

```js
var interval;
var counter = 0;
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

$('.start').click(function() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    numbers = _.shuffle(numbers);
    $('.table-cell.counter').html(counter++);
    $('.table-cell.numbers').each(function(index) {
      $(this).html(numbers[index]);
    });
  }, 500);
});

$('.stop').click(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900);
 .square {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
  margin: 1.66%;
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
  /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
  width: 90%;
  /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
  padding: 5%;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/*  For list */

ul {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 5% 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
li {
  margin: 0 0 0 5%;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ECECEC;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
.numbers {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 75px;
}
.text {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell text start">
        START
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell counter">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell text stop">
        STOP
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        6
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        7
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        8
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        9
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Thank you for the solution. I wish to ask that the counter goes on
>   incrementing beyond 9. Ideally when it reaches 9, it should come back
>   to 1. And one more thing I forgot to mention. Is it possible to change
>   color of the number in the grid that matches the stopped number? Eg.
>   If the number that comes after stopping is 4 so the number 4 in the
>   grid should turn yellow and next time when I start again, 4 should
>   disappear from the array. Therefore, when I click Start 9 times, all
>   colors in the grid should turn yellow and then the Start button should
>   give a message "All numbers done...." Thanks

```js
var interval;
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

$('.start').click(function() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (numbers.length) {
      numbers = _.shuffle(numbers);
      $('.table-cell.counter').html(numbers[0]);
    }
  }, 500);
});

$('.stop').click(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  numbers.shift(0);
  $('.table-cell.numbers').each(function() {
    var number = parseInt($(this).html());
    $(this).toggleClass('selected', numbers.indexOf(number) == -1);
  });
  if (!numbers.length) {
    $('.table-cell.start').html('All numbers done....').addClass('selected');
  }
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900);
 .square {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
  margin: 1.66%;
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
  /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
  width: 90%;
  /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
  padding: 5%;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/*  For list */

ul {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 5% 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
li {
  margin: 0 0 0 5%;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ECECEC;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
.numbers {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 75px;
}
.selected {
  color: yellow;
}
.text {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell text start">
        START
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell counter">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell text stop">
        STOP
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        6
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        7
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        8
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        9
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I wish to ask that the counter goes on incrementing beyond 9. Ideally when it reaches 9, it should come back to 1. And one more thing I forgot to mention. Is it possible to change color of the number in the grid that matches the stopped number? Eg. If the number that comes after stopping is 4 so the number 4 in the grid should turn yellow and next time when I start again, 4 should disappear from the array. Therefore, when I click Start 9 times, all colors in the grid should turn yellow and then the Start button should give a message "All numbers done...." Thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer which should help you with that. It doesn't do exactly what you asked as I feel i'd be doing the work for you rather than assisting. you just need to add few checks on `stop`. hope it helps.

Comment: Please dont misunderstand. I thought it may be a matter of 2-3 lines of extra code and that is why I asked for it. I will do some research to fulfil the desired output. Regarding the solution provided, I never wanted to shuffle the 3x3 grid, I just want the middle cell of top line to run the loop till 9 and restart until stop is pressed. In your solution, all 9 numbers in the grid are getting shuffled which i dont want. I just want the counter to work on start and stop and once it is stopped, the visible number should be highlithed in the grid. Thanks for your help. Appreciate a lot!

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I've updated my second answer to what you need.

Comment: 3 things I observed which is not making the code perfec. `1.` On first page load, if Stop is clicked before start, it by default highlights all numbers in yellow one after the other **sequentially** without shuffling and On first page load, if shuffle is done once and then if Stop button is clicked before start, it by default highlights all numbers in yellow one after other **randomly**. Actually, stop should work only if start is clicked. `2.` If Start button is clicked twice, it NEVER STOPS. `3.`  Shuffling effect doesnt work on mobile device. Can u pls have a look at it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
 var count = 0,interval;

   // Start the timer
    $(".start").click(function(){
    var result = $(".result");
        interval = setInterval(function(){
        $(".result").html(count++);
        },100); // 100 milliseconds
    });

    // Stop the timer 
    $(".stop").click(function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuofxovb/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to sound rude but, you should really learn to research these simple things by yourself, you will get better and faster results.

Here is some info on timing, http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Basic example:

```
var timer_id;

function onTick() {
    console.log("tick");
}

function start() {
    timer_id = setInterval( onTick, 1000); // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second interval
}

function stop() {
    if( timer_id)
        clearInterval( timer_id);
}
```

This just explains how to handle timing. onTick will be called every second with this, until stop() is called. just put start() and stop() in the onClick events in the html and in onTick you will want to update the contents of your timer.